# using Response.Write for redirecting to page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

When I use code like   `Response.Write("REDIRECT=http://mydomain.com/Result.aspx")` , The result page html is not getting displayed. Instead I am getting "`Page Not Found`" Error. Also in the url result page has text like " `Result.aspx%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%20PUBLIC`".

Please help me how can i redirect to result page properly.

Comment: As Muhammad says, it's far better to use `Response.Redirect`. I suspect that what you're seeing is because you allow response processing to continue after your `Response.Write`, and so it's appending HTML directly after the `.aspx` part of your redirect.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Response.Redirect`

```
Response.Redirect("http://mydomain.com/Result.aspx");
```

Comment: I am using it for  payment gateway, I can not use Response.Redirect

Comment: @Monesh have found the solution i m going through the same problem??

Answer (score 2):

on the page where you are writing `Response.Write` ,
 Remove the Following line from design file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or similar line.

For ex: if `Response.Write was` on `abc.aspx.cs` then remove the above mentioned line from `abc.aspx`

Hope this helps. Worked for me.

OR else if the pages are only for response/request purpose then remove everything from page except

`@page directive` Everyting means everything between `<html>` and `</html>` and also `DOCTYPE` line

this might work..

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Write("<script>window.location='http://mydomain.com/Result.aspx';</script>");`